# Javascript/TypeScript : asynchronicity problem with attribute of class with Socket.io?

Tags: javascript, typescript, socket.io

I am developing a WebSocket server with NodeJS and SocketIO. The code was originally in ES6 and I try to switch to TypeScript because I got a problem. I don't have the same result when I try to use attribute from the class or when I use a variable (const or let). It seems like it is asynchronous when I use an attribute from the class.
I think the easiest way to explain is to show you the two pieces of code and their output results. The problem occurs in a fake client I have created to build functional test of the WebSocket server:

1st Case:

```js
import {io, Socket, ManagerOptions} from "socket.io-client";


export default class Admin {
   private user: number;
   private data: Partial<ManagerOptions & SocketOptions>;
   private chatSocket: Socket;

   constructor(userId: number) {
     this.user = userId;
   }

   initQueryAndAuth() {
        this.data = {
            query: {
                user: this.user,
                room: "-1",
                role: 'administrator',
            },
            auth: {
                apiKey: process.env.SERVER_CHAT_API_KEY,
            }
        };
    }

   connectChat() {
        this.initQueryAndAuth();

        this.chatSocket = io("http://localhost:" + process.env.SERVER_PORT + "/chat", this.data);
        console.log(['From client', "0", this.chatSocket.connected]);
        setTimeout(() => {
            console.log(['From client', "3", this.chatSocket.connected]);
        },10);
        return Promise.all([this.joinChat(), this.onEventsChat()]);
    }

    joinChat() {
        return new Promise<void>(resolve => {
            console.log(['From client', "1", this.chatSocket.connected]);
            this.chatSocket.on("connect", () => {
                console.log(['From client', "4", this.chatSocket.connected]);
            });
            console.log(['From client', "2", this.chatSocket.connected]);
        })
    }
}
```

The console output :
[image]

2nd case (When I replace the attribute of class by a variable. I just write the code which changed) :

```js
   connectChat() {
        this.initQueryAndAuth();

        const test = io("http://localhost:" + process.env.SERVER_PORT + "/chat", this.data);
        console.log(['From client', "0", test.connected]);
        setTimeout(() => {
            console.log(['From client', "3", test.connected]);
        }, 10);
        return Promise.all([this.joinChat(test), this.onEventsChat()]);
    }

    joinChat(test) {
        return new Promise<void>(resolve => {
            console.log(['From client', "1", test.connected]);
            test.on("connect", () => {
                console.log(['From client', "4", test.connected]);
            });
            console.log(['From client', "2", test.connected]);
        })
    }
```

The output of the console :
[image]

If someone can explain to me why in the first case the output from the client n°4 is `false` and `true` in the second case, it would help me a lot.

Thank you for reading my post.
Have a nice day.

Comment: One obvious problem with the code (but not related to the difference you're asking about) would be that you never `resolve` the promise returned by `joinChat`

Comment: Your screenshot contains some `'From server'` output. Where does that come from? It's not in the code you posted.

Comment: I see no explanation other than that some code which you haven't posted (e.g. `onEventsChat()`) does overwrite the `this.chatSocket` property in your first example